# Почему разработчики языков не развивают GoTo?

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык, goto

Ныне GoTo кажется не таким мощным каким был, например в Фортране...
Почему разработчики языков не развивают GoTo?

Ведь можно было бы добавить перепрыгивание из одной фукнции в другую, из одной сборки в другую, из в класса в класс.

Это было бы, на мой взгляд, просто прекрасно и ведь производительность выросла бы в разы за счет того, что комплиторобу пришлось бы меньше преобразовывать GoTo, которые были написаны с душой в бездушные ассемблерные GoTo.

Comment: Хм-м... Развивать goto - это как? Сделать более гоутушным? Он есть. Надо - пользуйтесь...

Comment: А почему бы лонг джамп не сделать ешё лонг джампней? У автора вопроса сегодня явно хорошее настроение.

Comment: Да ладно, за что минус-то? Нормальный вопрос, хоть и немного провокационный.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, производительность в разы бы не выросла, ибо компиляторы и так достаточно хорошо оптимизируют, и явные переходы только бы мешали оптимизации.

Кстати, приведите пример, где, как вам кажется, производительность бы выросла в разы...

Во-вторых, код пишется для человека, а не для машины :), а наличие таких `goto` резко бы "замусоривало" код и делало его нечитаемым.

Ну, и есть масса неприятностей - типа

```
void f()
{
    ...
    goto in_g:
}

void g()
{
    Obj a;
    a.do_something();

    in_g:
    a.do_another();
```

И каким должен быть объект `a` в строке после перехода? Как создан, какими значениями инициализирован?

Таких проблем - масса...

Comment: ну ладно, преимущества есть . Особенно в цитируемом Фортране. Да и большинство хорошо оптимизированных алгоритмов делают с гоуту. Использовать этот оператор нужно с большой осторожностью, но при грамотном подходе выигрыш возможен (не в разы, возожно, но возможен)

Answer (score 2):

Когда этих GOTO становится много в коде то уследить за ветвлением программы очень сложно, хотя и можно. Человеческий мозг то же ограниченный ресурс и вместо количества он лучше воспринимает осмысленные конструкции (их проще запомнить). С обычным современным процессом ветвления код ограничивается небольшими блоками, такой блок мозгу проще "переварить", чем бесконечно неоднократно прослеживать весь код целиком, и из этого истекает простая закономерность, меньше думаешь - меньше ошибок. Вот и перешли от количества к качеству.

Нравится GOTO пишите на старых языках.

Comment: Некоторые использует это как возможность удержаться на работе... Мол, другие не разберутся в этом коде. Тут и такие (сомнительные, но) преимущества

Comment: @DNS - это не поможет если пришел человек который любит рефракторинг.

Comment: Ой, я Вас умоляю... Обфускация позволяет джампить даже между байтов одной команды. Успехов пришедшему...

Comment: @DNS свой код шифровать еще хуже. однажды вы потеряете исходник ну и следовательно работу.

вот будет весело если конкурент его тупо удалит если найдет где вы его прячете ) . Хотя если кто то увидит свою работу в виде обфускацированного кода то с его стороны глупо будет вообще устраиваться на такую работу.

Я бы просто про это сказал начальнику этого парня что мол не могу работать так это не возможно по причине и тд. Ну и если директор не дурень то челу головы не сносить

Comment: это совсем другая сказка... Вопрос про `goto` - и он (вопрос) имеет право на существование (хотя, наверняка, дубликат). Я и сам сторонник гоуту для высокооптимизированных мат-алгоритмов. Этот оператор дает выигрыш по сравнению с без-гоуту стилем

Comment: @DNS мы сначала про множественное goto говорили, а потом про обфускацию. Это две разные вещи. Так что выбирайте сказку какая вам нравится.

Comment: Вы восприняли обфускацию сильно глобально. Я имел в виду простое запутывание кода. Гоуту для этого - палочка-выручалочка. Без шифрования - просто перепутанный стиль. Я неоднократно пользовался алгоритмами с гоуту. Для мат-вычислений они превосходны. Например, с тройными циклами (для матричных операций) выходы при помощи гоуту разобрать совсем непросто - так надо быть не только программистом, но и математиком. Но прирост в скорости есть. Не в разы, но в проценты...))

Comment: @DNS а если не глобально думать. то сколько этих goto в код не ставь то простейший оптимизатор элементарно исправит ситуацию.

Comment: Исправит??? В некоторых случаях это приведет к замедлению кода. Повторяться не буду

Comment: @DNS а некоторые случаи это какие?

Comment: Ой, всё! Это мат-алгоритмы. В основном матричные, особенно, связанные с собственными числами и векторами.

Comment: @DNS при обработки исходника будут простые алгоритмы. заворачивание в циклы + избавления от ненужных циклов. Ну и возможно (но не обязательно) это подавление дублирующего кода. Ну а потом рефракторинг если хочется красиво.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала, код пишется не для машины, а для человека. Читать логику с `goto` сложно, и понять её ещё сложнее. Кроме того, использование `goto` «подбивает» авторов кода решать проблемы не путём понимания структуры и написания программы так, чтобы структура была очевидна, а путём простого механического перехода на нужный кусок кода.

Об этом ещё в 1968 году писал Дейкстра в своей знаменитой статье *Go To Statement Considered Harmful*:

> The unbridled use of the *go to* statement has an immediate consequence that it becomes terribly hard to find a meaningful set of coordinates in which to describe the process progress.
>
> The *go to* statement as it stands is just too primitive; it is too much an invitation to make a mess of one’s program.

Кроме того, в современных языках есть проблемы, обусловленные там, что блоки имеют определённый смысл. Что делать с переменными, инициализацию которых вы пропускаете? Что делать, если стек функции, из которой вы выпрыгиваете, не совпадает со стеком функции, в которую вы попадаете? Что делать, если вы из статической функции перепрыгиваете в нестатическую? Что делать, если вы хотите впрыгнуть внутрь генератора или async-функции? Что делать, если вы хотите впрыгнуть внутрь замыкания? Вопросов здесь намного больше, чем ответов.

Именно поэтому `goto` в тех языках, в которых он сохранился, имеет достаточно ограниченную функциональность. Перепрыгивание между функциями запрещено, и вряд ли когда-либо будет разрешено. Развиваются скорее более структурированные части языков.

А если вам часто нужен `goto`, скорее всего вы хотите либо state-машину, либо используете слишком высокоуровневый язык.